# What are the names of conch shell ( shankh ) used by the warriors in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

- What are the names of conch shells used by the Pandava and Kaurava (notable) warriors in Mahabharata and why were they named so?
- What was the speciality about each of them ?

Comment: @Ganesh What was the edit in the question? You added space? What was the need? Avoid trivial edits.

Comment: You asked about Conch shells of Kaurava as well as pandava(105+1(yuyutsu if you consider him)). The answer you accepted partially answers your question, this means your question is inconsistent with the answer accepted and you have not framed your question correctly.

Comment: @ Sree Charan I think nobody post/edit in this website for points or badges.It is only to share our knowledge and learn about Sanatana Dharma.The edit was by mistake and not intented for any other purpose.

Comment: Each shell has special abilities like panchajanya sounds reach the enemies no matter where they hide also sound leading the path where his enemy is .
With this shell God Krishna found the hidden door to hell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 1, The conch shells used by Lord Krishna and Pandavas.The slokas are as follows,

पाञ्चजन्यं हृषीकेशो देवदत्तं धनंजयः।

पौण्ड्रं दध्मौ महाशङ्खं भीमकर्मा वृकोदरः।।1.15।।

अनन्तविजयं राजा कुन्तीपुत्रो युधिष्ठिरः।

नकुलः सहदेवश्च सुघोषमणिपुष्पकौ।।1.16।।

**Pancajanya** — the conchshell of Lord Sri Krishna. It was taken from the demon Pancajana after Krishna slew him.

**Anantavijaya** — name of King Yudhisthira’s conch shell, meaning “Unending victory.”

**Paundra** — the terrific conchshell of Bhima.

**Devadatta** — the conch of Arjuna which was obtained by Maya Danava from Varuna. The name means, “God given.”

**Manipuspaka** — name of Sahadeva’s conch-shell, meaning “Jewel bracelet.”

**Sughosa** — the conch shell of Nakula, meaning “Making a pleasant sound.”

The very next sloka mentions about various kings and Maharathis blowing their respective conch shells which  King of Kasi, Sikhandi, Virata, Sätyaki, Drupada, Abhimanyu.But not their names.

Comment: Paundraka means which has pundra on it. Pundra means marks or lines on it. Pundra as in Urdhwa pundra, Teriyek pundra. It may also mean white lotus flower.

Answer (score 3):

This is the mention of the conch shells.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06025.htm

> **And Hrishikesha blew (the conch called) Panchajanya** and **Dhananjaya (that called) Devadatta**; and **Vrikodara of terrible deeds blew the huge conch (called) Paundra**. **And Kunti's son king Yudhishthira blew (the conch called) Anantavijaya**; **while Nakula and Sahadeva, (those conches called respectively) Sughosa and Manipushpaka**.

Krishna's conch is the panchajanya

Arjuna's conch was Devadatta

Bhima's huge conch was Paundra

Yudhisthira's conch was Anantavijaya

Nakula's conch was Sughosa

Sahadeva's conch was Manipushpaka.

Comment: During the suspension period if the suspended user creates a new account then that only increases the suspension period. You should not have created this account Fun Life. You should return after the 30 days period is over.

Comment: Were the Conch used in Ramayana?